# Not getting data when trying to create multiple inner join on 2 columns from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table and data like below:

Employee:

```
Id      DepartmentId
1       100
2       100
3       100
```

LeaveRequest:

```
Id    SentFromEmployeeId    SentToEmployeeId
1     1                     2
2     1                     2
3     2                     3
```

LeaveUpdateLogs:

```
Id      RequestedDate             LeaveRequestId     Status
1       2021-11-01 11:55:56       1                  Pending
2       2021-11-02 10:55:56       1                  Accepted
3       2021-11-03 11:55:56       1                  Accepted
4       2021-11-04 09:55:56       1                  Declined
5       2021-11-05 10:55:56       1                  Closed

6       2021-11-06 05:55:56       2                  Pending
7       2021-11-07 05:55:56       2                  Accepted
8       2021-11-08 02:55:56       2                  Accepted
9       2021-11-09 05:55:56       2                  Declined
10       2021-11-10 05:55:56       2                  Closed
```

Now here I want to calculate statistics as below for a particular department:

Total number of requests `sent` and `received` for `DepartmentId 100`.

But I am confused here for getting data for "`Sent`" and "`Received`" like below:

```
select SentFromEmployeeId,SentToEmployeeId,* from LeaveUpdateLogs l
inner join LeaveRequest lr on l.LeaveRequestId = lr.Id
inner join Employee e1 on e1.Id = lr.SentFromEmployeeId
inner join Employee e2 on e2.Id = lr.SentToEmployeeId
where (l.RequestedDate >= '2021-11-01' and l.RequestedDate < '2021-11-16')
and (e1.DepartmentId =100 or e2.DepartmentId = 100)
```

But this doesn't return any data although I have "25" records between this 2 dates. When I comment out this 3 lines:

```
inner join Employee e1 on e1.Id = lr.SentFromEmployeeId
inner join Employee e2 on e2.Id = lr.SentToEmployeeId
(e1.DepartmentId =100 or e2.DepartmentId = 100)
```

Then query is working fine but I want to get the data for particular department.

Can someone please help me fix this logic?

Comment: The query you posted should not return any rows for the sample data you provided. The dates you have in your query are for the year 2021 but all of your sample data is from 2020. Also the department in your query is 100 but your sample it is 10
.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, but thats just for the sample data but I do have data for this month in my actual table. I think issue is in the logic that's why I didn't updated the date. I will update the date in sample data

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry for the typo. Fixed the data. thanks for pointing out

Comment: Are there two LeaveUpdateLogs with Id = 6 or is it a typo?

Comment: Query works for me.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. However, the query you posted would return all the rows in your sample data. I think you need to figure out how to reproduce the issue you are facing.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but it returns 10 rows: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eb8e46f5812c454b0c41f31bdefb5970

Comment: @SeanLange But based on problem description, do you think I would need 2 inner join or we can do this with 1 join also? What do you think about the logic?

Comment: @Carlos Do you think the logic of using 2 inner join is correct or it should be just 1 join ? What do you think about the logic?

Comment: I am guessing that ultimately you really want to have some actual information about these two employees other than their Id. As such you would need to join to that table twice because you need values from two different rows.

Comment: @SeanLange I want to get data for employee from a single department who have "Received" and "Sent" leave request in a particular department. Based on this data, I will calculate statistics for sent like "accepted" = x, "declined" = x, "closed" = x and for received too like  "accepted"= x, "declined"= x, "closed" = x.  I have group by logic but then the only problem is figuring out the logic for department because I don't have departmentid in this leave request tables.

Comment: If you don't care if a given row was "Sent From" or "Sent To" and only that either of those people are from a given department then you only need a single join. At this point your question is all over the place with no actual question being asked.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, you are right with that point that I only care that either of those people are from a given department. So if I had to use single join that how it should be? Can you give me a little hint or pointer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I think you are only asking how to join on multiple values here are a couple ways of you could tackle this.

```
inner join Employee e1 on e1.Id in (lr.SentFromEmployeeId, lr.SentToEmployeeId)
```

Or

```
inner join Employee e1 on e1.Id = lr.SentFromEmployeeId 
                       OR e1.Id = lr.SentToEmployeeId
```